# Share memory between jars

Tags: java, jar, shared-memory

I have several private jars in my project and I need them to write and read values to\from the same b-dimensional array.

EDIT: Now I got anotger reqirement - to allow a C++\MFC app to write to this shared memory. So, all in all, I have a c++ app writing to the shared memory and jars reading from it. What is the best way to acheive it? Maybe a web service?

If yes - how to implenet that?

Comment: Depends how you are using the jars.  Are you starting a separate VM for each - e.g. java -jar myjar1.jar and java -jar myjar2.jar.  If you are then you can't.  If you are using them as libraries in an application then you'll need to explain or show the code.

Comment: I'm gonna use them as application external libraries. What would you suggest me Dan? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can;

- run all the jars in the same JVM.  This way they will share memory natively.
- use memory mapped files, possibly on a ram drive if you don't need persistence.

Chronicle has a number of libraries to make using memory mapped files easier as it

- offers thread safe operations into native memory.
- builds some useful data structures such as a [key-value store](http://openhft.net/products/chronicle-map/) and [persisted queue](http://openhft.net/products/chronicle-queue/)
- support more efficient serialization and zero-copy access to native memory.

For information on all the [Apache 2.0 Open Source libraries](http://openhft.net/hft-products/)

BTW Chronicle also supports distribution of its data structures which means the jars don't have to be running on the same machine.

Comment: Thank you Peter. 1. The jars will be imported to my application. It means that they will run on the dsaem jar, right? If so, still I cannot understand how can they read and write to the same array? 2. Mapped files is about maps. So how can I utilize an array with it? 3. I screend the Chornicle home page, and couldn't find a solution for a b-dimensional array. Do you  know what can be helpful for me there?  Thank you

Comment: 1. You don't run an application in a jar, a program runs and it uses many jars to provide the code and resources.  How you do this is up to you. When you memory map a file into two programs at once, they can both see each others copy of the data, provided you do this in a thread safe manner. 2. Memory mapping has little to do with with Map data structure.  It is about how virtual memory us mapped to actual memory and in this case a file. 3. You can implement your own N-dimensional array using direct memory mapped files in the same manner that N-dimensional arrays are implemented in C.